# How can I adjust the Input type="number" inner spinner style on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, input

I've been trying all day to remove the "up" and "down" button in the input type="number" on Mozilla Firefox Developer Edition and I tried all the CSS style that I could find on here or else, but still doesn't work to hide them.

I'm working on Firefox Developer build 54.0a2 and it was fine on previous build with that CSS:

```
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (or some similar) cross-browser hack if you want - if you do it well nobody can see those arrows ever exist:

```css
.hidearrows {
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:-21px;
  background-color:#fff;
  z-index:10;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  margin-top:1px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" step="1" value="1" /><span class="hidearrows"></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6c3brbjo/

Comment: That's not cross-browser, it's not working properly on Chrome. 
I'm not looking for a "hack" like that, what i'm looking for is : 
why it was working two weeks ago and today it's not. 
And find an actual solution.

Comment: It IS working on Chrome? However - yes it is a workaround. If it worked two weeks ago with the appearance property and now it is not you maybe should contact the firefox development team and ask about this problem (guess its here): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/